# Spring, Authentication with database

Tags: java, database, spring, authentication

I want to secure endpoints using Basic Auth.

When I try to log in with correct username and password - everything is working.

My problem is that when I try to log in with wrong username or password - I get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
```

How can I fix it?

```
SecurityConfig.java

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_QUERY = "SELECT u.username, r.role FROM user u " +
                                                    "INNER JOIN user_role ur ON u.id = ur.user_id " +
                                                    "INNER JOIN role r ON ur.role_id = r.id " +
                                                    "WHERE u.username=?";

    private static final String USERS_QUERY = "SELECT username, password, is_active FROM user WHERE username=?";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORITIES_QUERY)
                .dataSource(dataSource).and()
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAuthority("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

}
```

Comment: body for `userDetailsService()`

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this (http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/) link. It's about "Spring Security + Hibernate Annotation Example"